# Unlimited for...loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop

I have 3 elements that match to `#sweet` ID. I have a function like this:

```
var element=document.querySelectorAll("#sweet");

for (var y=0; y<element.length; y++)
{

if (element[y].nodeName == "DIV")
  {
    element[y].innerHTML='';
    var length=element[y].offsetWidth;

    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
       console.log(i);
    }

 /////////////////////////
 var resizeTimer = 0;
    function doResize()
    {
        if (resizeTimer)
            clearTimeout(resizeTimer);

        resizeTimer = setTimeout(function() {rainbow(n, color);}, 0);
    }

    doResize();
 ////////////////////////

  }
  else if (element[y].nodeName == "SPAN")
  {
    console.log("span");
  }
```

}

But there is problem. It prints `span` word unlimitedly in console. But it must print 2 times, because I have 1 div element with `#sweet` ID and 2 span elements with `#sweet` ID. What cause to this problem? Maybe, it is because i have settimeout function, but I need this function, I don't want to remove it, have another solving way?

Comment: What you've got there is a syntax error. You're going to have to describe more clearly what it is you want to do.

Comment: @Pointy I described clearly, I just wanted to use items in one array in javascript function

Answer (score 3):

You can pass your variables as a parameter by making them into an array:

```
var doitman = function(items, option2){
    var item1 = items[0];
    var item2 = items[2];
    // your code here
}
var items = [item1, item2, item3];
doitman( items, option2 );
```

I think you should look at [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) on arrays.

Comment: Note that `var items = [item1, item2, item3];` is generally accepted as best practice for declaring an array (rather than using `new Array(...)`).

Answer (score 2):

```
function doitman (ary, option2) {
   var item1 = ary [0];
   var item2 = ary [1];
   var item3 = ary [2];

   // whatever
}

doitman ( [1, 2, 3], option );
```